# Query for finding the kid with the highest grade level in a school that is working on a project?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There's a school project that is given to kids in various grade level(only one senior though). Sophomores will mentor Freshmen, Juniors will mentor sophomores, and one senior will mentor juniors.

I made the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [studentID] [varchar](50) primary key   NOT NULL,
    [MentorID] [varchar](50),
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT](
    [PID] [int] primary key  NOT NULL,
    [ProjectName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorksOn](
    [SID] [varchar](50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES School(studentID) NOT NULL,
    [ProjID] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PROJECT(PID) NOT NULL,
    primary key(SID,PID),
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm trying to write a query that can retrieve the name of the highest level person working on a project. So project1 can have a freshman, 2 sophomores, and a junior. It will return the name of that junior.

I'm wondering if I should add `[GradeLevel]` to the school table? Would it make it easier?

Also, let's say project2 has one freshman and two sophomores. It should return the name of the two sophomores.

edit- query I'm trying

```
SELECT p.ProjectName AS "Project", s.Name AS "Highest ranking memeber/s"
    FROM PROJECT p
    inner JOIN School s 
        ON p.PID = s.ProjectID
    where min(s.Level)-- level 1 being a senior, 2 a junior.
group by PROJECT.ProjectName
```

if Project1 has bob(freshmen),jule(sophmore), betty(junior), then it should return betty for project1.

Comment: Please include the query you have already tried.

Comment: Not sure, but I think it'll be better adding it on project or worksOn, this will be as a reference of the student level. Let's say one worked on a project as freshmen, a couple of years later, the same one worked on a project as senior !. so you kept a history record for that student, which can help you to get all the projects that have been worked on during his or her study along with the grade level. do you get what I mean ?

Comment: I see you've changed the original structure. If I understand the requirements correctly, Junior A might be mentoring sophomore B on one project, but mentoring  sophomore C on another project - meaning that the `MentorId` does not belong on the `School` table, but on the `WorksOn` table.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, but I also want to see for a given student, who his mentor is. For example, for the sophmore the mentorID would be the studentID of the junior.

Comment: Yes, but the mentoring relationship is project dependent, so you need to put the `MentorId` column in the `WorksOn` table

Comment: I see. Before I change it, can you think of a query that can get the project names and names of the highest level people working on the project as I have it currently?

Comment: Yes, use `top 1 with ties` and `order by level` (assuming level is a member of the `school` table).

Answer (score 0):

You have a flaw in your current design.
You currently have two different tables linking the `studentId` to the `MentorId` (btw, `varchar(50)` is probably not the best choice for an `id` column, but that's a different story).

If you want to keep track of who is mentoring who, you can either keep that relationship in the `School` table, or in the `WorksOn` table (poor name, IMHO. a name like `MentorToStudent` would convey the meaning of this table much better).

If all you care about is the students grade level, but you don't care about which particular Junior is mentoring which particular sophomore, then instead of having the `MentorID` column you should remove the `WorksOn` table and simply add the `GradeLevel` column to the `School` table.

So based on these choices, the query to get whoever have the highest grade level for a project will change - the first option would probably require a recursive cte, while the second option would only require to know how to order the grade levels (which is easy, if you have them in their own table with a name and id - and that's probably going to be a good idea in both options).

Comment: The MentorId foreign key should be ProjectID. WorksOn table shows which person works on which project.

Comment: Same flaw, different columns. That same relationship also exists in the `School` table.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow. The primary key of school and project tables are foriegn keys of works on table. Also I do care about which particular "Junior" is mentoring the sophomore.

Comment: My point is that the `WorksOn` table is redundant, since you already have the connection between `studentId` and `projectId` in the `School` table.

Comment: I got your point. I did that so that a student can't be added to a project twice. Would it be better to take the project ID from school table and keep WorksOn table in terms of performance? I also put the query I am trying above to get the name/s of the highest ranking people working on the project.